# Is it advantageous to accept a more specific job title over a more generic one?

Tags: software-industry, negotiation, job-offer

I have been working for more than 2 years as a Software Engineer, and my work has been more of a cross domain position, rather than specific technologies.

I am now being offered a job as "Software Engineer - Windows Mobile App".

How will a more specific job title affect my future opportunities?  Will I be passed over for other possible opportunities as a result of this?

Comment: Does [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/importance-and-flexibility-in-job-title-presented-in-job-offer) answer your concerns? It looks to be very similar and there are some great answers about this question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, more specific job titles are not limiting in your future opportunities if you play them right.

If you are looking to stay in that field (Windows Mobile dev in this case), it is definitely advantageous for you to take that job title.

If you are not planning on staying in that field long term, I have two things:

1. Why are you accepting this job if it is not something you are truly
   interested in? (it may be a financial reason, that you just need a
   job)
2. Are you comfortable with presenting yourself as a generalist, even
   with the more specific job title?

I'd say there is little disadvantage to accepting the job as-is.  If you end up working on other things, you can talk to your boss and adjust it in the future.

Too much importance is placed on job titles in many cases - you should seek out new opportunities by presenting your accomplishments, not your label.

Answer (score 1):

When moving from Company A to Company B the job title are almost irrelevant. I have worked for companies that have very detailed title and job descriptions, and I have worked for companies that lumped all technical jobs into one track with 5 levels. Therefore nobody is overly concerned about what job title you have on your resume, they care about the description and what you have accomplished.

Now within a company job titles do matter. They get mapped to salary ranges, some are at the top of their track and some are at the bottom. For the same pay you would prefer a tile that does allow for salary growth without requiring a promotion; but you also want to know that there is another title above your current title. Without room to grow you can lose motivation to improve, and your pay will stagnate.

In some cases managers are too strict about titles when reviewing internal candidates, and refuse to acknowledge that the specific title was selected due to funding constraints are the need to fit a person into a project org chart. They sometimes eliminate a great candidate because of a perceived mismatch of title.

Ask your manager where this title fits in the company list of job title to decide if that particular title will limit your growth.