# Getting interviews for jobs I'm under-qualified for because of current title. How to proceed?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, careers

I graduated last year and was fortunate enough to land a product management internship which grew into part-time job as an Associate Product manager at a large ERP company like Oracle. However, my day-to-day tasks are more aligned with research, some requirements defining, and customer interaction. It's not the experience of a typical associate product manager. However, because of my title I'm getting lots of job interviews where employers gradually realize that my experience is not up to par in the interview. I've been taking courses and reading product management books and feel like I can accomplish as a real entry level product manager. But have no real experience to show for it. Any advice?

Comment: Alternatively, you could apply for jobs that are more closely aligned with your experience rather than your job title...?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. I am also doing this. But I was hoping there was someone that has experience leveraging their title to obtain a better opportunity, despite actual experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to walk the walk if you have not had the real world experience.  If you don't have that, you can only really look at trying to find somewhere that will help you grow fully into that role, which means starting down a peg and working your way up.

Comment: Ask you manager to have your job title reevaluated.  It helps to have a job title that more closely aligns with your actual job responsibilities.

Comment: Related: [Job Title / Job Description Mismatch](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32053/job-title-job-description-mismatch) and [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Answer (score 2):

This type of situation is not in any way rare. It happens with a lot of people.

So, you go on and include what you have done in the job, along with the techniques and tools, and also the learnings you have gained from the role.
Yes, do it honestly.

And, in the interviews you can prove yourself by letting the interviewer know about your online learning and courses.

And do add the courses you have taken in the **courses** section. If they are MOOC's then include them in the certificaitions section.

If they are minor courses or if you are learning from online blogs and resources, then include it in the summary section, which can go somewhat like this:

> I strongly believe in self-driven education, as most of my efforts in
>   my professional life have been fueled by online education.
>
> < Include some more lines >

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic substitute for actual experience and knowledge in your field. You are applying for jobs you are not qualified to do yet. So stop that and apply for the ones you are qualified for with the intent of learning what you need to get a better position.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of experience more aligns with a Business Analyst, IMO.

Maybe you'll have some more luck with interviews for BA positions, where requirements gathering and reporting to internal and external resources are the only real solid requirements.

Its also a great job that is generally pretty easy to get, and tends to expose you to gradually more complex things. If nothing else, you will learn how to throw some business-ese at an interviewer, and make them less concerned about your level of experience and competence.