# New Job -- Help Defining Title?

Tags: new-job, title

I have recently been hired at a retain search firm that is a startup, and the proposed title at the initial interview was "office manager." This feels like a huge step backward for me, and it also doesn't seem to encompass the scope of the job: human resources, accounting & financials, marketing, process development, and more. Do you have any suggestions for what else I could propose? My new boss is open to a different title, I just need to come up with some good ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Why should you have only one job title?  In a startup, it's common for people to "wear a lot of hats", so it seems reasonable that each had should have its own title.

Comment: The job title itself is not nearly as important as the actual responsibilities. See [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32053/job-title-job-description-mismatch) and [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume) for examples.

Comment: I was "Investor Relations & Human Resources Manager" at a PE shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My new boss is open to a different title

Make full use of this. When you go looking for your next job - which maybe some time away - your title will matter.
At the same time, don't get pushy with your new company.

> the proposed title at the initial interview was "office manager."

The problem here I think is with the word "office". Try to change this to something else. 
You could try Manager, Growth or something else. I think going into jobs, a title that talks Business Development is more likely to be appreciated than others.