# Mention a private partnership for a Master Thesis on a CV

Tags: resume

I am currently involved in an Engineering Master Program in a European country and I will soon begin the last year of my program during which I will spend approximately half a year working on a Master Thesis. A Master Thesis in my country is usually not mentioned on a CV. Employers know you have done one, but they do not care as it is considered completely academic work.

However, I have a Master Thesis in partnership with a private company. This company is pretty big and renowned and I consider the opportunity to work with them a great chance and a very interesting experience. My work will probably be used by them for practical purposes.

I would like to mention this somehow on my CV, with the purpose to show my willingness to achieve solutions to *practical* problems

A friend suggested to mention this experience as an Internship, but I do not like this option as I do not work for them all the time, and I am not sure that the company view this experience as an Internship (BTW I will ask them to be sure that they agree with what I will write).

**How can I mention this experience on my CV?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: The OP is essentially asking how s/he can make it clear in his or her CV that their Masters is a bit more than the average Masters. That doesn't really seem too localised...

Comment: @Math I removed a lot of text because the amount frightened the reader (at least me). You can [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/33097/edit) the question further if you want.

Comment: why you would not even mention your thesis subject on your CV its normal practice to list this sort of thing plus any other publications

And how does the employer "know" you have done this thesis if you don't tell them about it

Answer (score 1):

**CVs are all about showing off** and being arrogant. You'd have to be super, duper arrogant for it to seem odd.

Does you CV have an "achievements" section listing things you've done that you think employers might be impressed by / things you are particularly proud of? If not, consider adding one.

That will leave you with an appropriate space to **write a brief blurb about what you've done,** e.g. "Successfully partnered with a prestigious commercial company to complete my Masters thesis, creating a real-world application for my studies."

Since you're not sure what position you hold with this company, write two or three versions of the blurb, one for an intern position, others for any other likely job titles you might be given (or might like!), so all they have to do is choose the one that fits. If you're not sure what your title should be, this older Workplace question might help... [How do I choose an appropriate job title?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-choose-an-appropriate-job-title)

Answer (score 0):

This is a professional experience. If you feel that you have to give a context the internship seems appropriate. An interested recruiter can always ask for more details during the interview. 
Alternatively you may describe it as consulting but a recruiter may consider that odd given your career level.