# What should I call this position?

Tags: title

We're a small company. We've just hired a guy for a lot of different responsibilities, including analytics, graphic design, social media marketing, research, and UX design.

Suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Unfortunately generating these sort of ideas is completely outside the scope of Workplace SE. Here we provide advice as to how one might navigate office politics, etc. That being said, it sounds to me like _"Jack-of-all-trades"_ would be appropriate.

Comment: I suggest: Daenerys Stormborn of the House Targaryen, the first of her name, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar and the First Men, Lady of the Seven Kingdoms and Protector of the Realm, the Unburnt, Mother of Dragons, Breaker of Chains, Queen of Meereen, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I choose an appropriate job title?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-choose-an-appropriate-job-title)

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the more "on-topic" question you didn't ask: "how can i find a name for this position":

Sit down with the guy and find or make up a name... maybe something that describes all of his work, maybe just for the roles he wants to emphasize or what he wants to be his position after the company grew. Maybe even something less common like "Online-PR Guru" or "Marketing Guy".

Answer (score 1):

One of the beauties of small business is that you can literally call the position whatever you want.

Here's what I would do.  Sit down with the person you hired and ask him/her, "What would **you** call this position?" and listen.  *Give the person a preliminary title and then revisit it again in 90 days and have the discussion again, when you are all more comfortable deciding what the predominate roles of that job entail.*

At a small company, the main value of a title of a unique position is job satisfaction for the person holding it.  He's not going to want some title that doesn't match his career path and in many cases a title or position is a source of pride.

Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  You can have a can of succotash and call it soup or stew or whatever. It doesn't change what's in the can.