# What are the job titles for people, managing internal startups departments?

Tags: company-culture, title, position, hierarchy

Many big corporations have internal innovation departments, startup departments etc. Basically, that's the place, where they create internal startups. It also could be intracorporate venture fund, which invests into internal and external (but still related to their area of interests) startups.

I'm trying to figure out all the most common job titles for the people, who deal with internal/external startups inside big companies. Could you give me a hand with that?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Are you planning to create a culture like that in your organization and wonder how to name the positions created by that initiative? Or are you interested in such a position yourself and want to know what job titles to look out for?

Comment: This will vary **wildly** from company to company (and county might play a role too).

Comment: @Philipp no, I'm selling to these people

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I choose an appropriate job title?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-choose-an-appropriate-job-title)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Navigating the Workplace as described in the [help].

Answer (score 3):

In a "scientific" discussion, they would be called generically **"intrapreneurs"**, especially if the activity is started at their initiative. **Intrapreneurship** is inside companies what **entrepreneurship** is outside companies.

What are these people called in each company? They can be called any way the company wants, even if their title does not fit their job. Take the example where **managers** end up calling themselves **leaders** just because it sounds better.