# Job title holding me back?

Tags: title

I have a Master's Degree in EE from a decent university, and have worked in a couple startups through out my career, this is my second job and I have 5+ years of total relevant work experience. I have been working as a Jr. Systems Engineer for nearly three years now. I have the following questions.

1. Am I being undervalued, should I ask my manager for a better title and a raise?
2. If I start applying for jobs elsewhere, will it affect my chances of getting a call? will it make me seem like a entry level candidate instead of an experienced candidate to the HR and hiring manager.
3. Should I attempt to 'hide' my title in my resume and during my interviews? is it worth it?

Comment: Both questions (raise and hiding title) have been asked/answered before: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid) and [Omit Junior from job title on resume - likely outcome?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30990/omit-junior-from-job-title-on-resume-likely-outcome)

Comment: Related to the second question @Brandin linked and arguably the parent question on the topic of using your own titles: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: I recently got offered a job at a large tech company as a Sr. EE. In my resume I just had EE as the title. When they ran the background check they asked me to resubmit my resume. This time I mentioned the exact titles and dates in paranthesis under the EE title in the resume. I do not think I was deceptive here, as my actual title was not justifying my actual responsibilities. tldr; do not worry too much if you have put in a generic title on your resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I being undervalued, should I ask my manager for a better title and a raise?

Possibly. Check if you have a career ladder/path in your company. See if you fulfill most of the requirements. If you do, ask for a raise/promotion. If you don't, talk to the manager and establish next steps for promotion.

> If I start applying for jobs elsewhere, will it affect my chances of getting a call?...

Omit the Jr. part. It's unlikely that they will go into detail about that.

> Should I attempt to 'hide' my title in my resume and during my interviews? is it worth it?

Same as above. You could even state that "Jr." was inadequate and it's one of the reasons to pursue your career goals in a new company.

Answer (score 1):

I see no Problem in asking them to change the Title. It does not cost you employer anything and you definitely have enough years to be out of the "junior" zone. The Role could be junior though, maybe also take on more responsibility?
As for the raise, we can't say because it does not depend on your title but on the worth of your work and what you are currently getting. Normally you should ask for a raise once a year anyways but I would maybe make that unrelated to the Title-thing.

In an resume just state you last title then.