# Is it ethical to discuss regarding received confirmation letter?

Tags: job-change, job-description, probation

Today I received my confirmation letter in my workplace ***as a Software Developer*** after completing my probation.

I applied to the advertisement which was looking for an ***Associate Software Engineer***.(*Software Developer < Associate Software Engineer*) And I got recruited.This is my current workplace.

Designation is something important when looking for future career opportunities.

I haven't completed my college degree yet. But this is also not my first job either. So when I joined the company, they didn't talk anything about my designation.(*They were aware that when I join the company that I haven't completed my college studies*)

I thought when I get confirm, they may change the designation to Associate Software Engineer.But this has not happened.

**Will it be a wise action to talk this with the HR manager?** (I still don't have the degree)

> I'm not in a situation to move to another company

Comment: Is there a reason the title is significant to you?  Most companies have their own system for titles, and they don't necessarily translate to other companies.  Your job description (official and what you actually do) are what your next employer will want to look at.

Comment: Did you say on your resume or in your interview that you *had* completed your degree?

Comment: Designation matter when applying for another company. So, there is clear difference between SD and ASE. ASE is someone who apply the disciplines of Engineering.

Comment: If there's a problem or miscommunication then obviously you should talk to someone about it yes - it may be deliberate, in which case you should ask for an explanation, or it may have been an accident. Either way it's a reasonable conversation to have. But ideally you'd have done that straight away.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3347/2322) - it's very similar if not the same?

Comment: You might want to reword the title of your question, this has nothing to do with ethics and you're not really worried about the confirmation letter, you're asking about your job title.

Comment: BTW, Software Developer is very generic and I have never even heard of an associate s/w developer and I have been in the industry for 25 years.  The s/w developer title will suite you very well on your result now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too uncommon - they may feel that you don't completely fill out all the requirements for an Associate Software Engineer (whatever that is), but they still want to hire you and hopefully you can grow into the role.

You should feel free to talk to the HR manager or contact regarding the confirmation letter - avoid being confrontational, and ask the question along the lines of how the Developer and Engineer roles differ, and ask about the potential for advancement. It shows you're keen to improve yourself.

As for designation being important when moving on - it's a bit early to be thinking about moving on when you've only just received confirmation of your new position. Also, it probably doesn't matter as much as you think - except for team or project leads over developers - what matters more are the responsibilities and achievements in a role. A software engineer at company X may be labelled a programmer at company Y, but have the same actual responsibilities.

Comment: stay in the same position even if there is no positive feedback after talk with HR ? or should I step-out from the company?

Comment: I'd stay if it's the only offer you currently have - hold it for at least 12 months, and move on - at least then you have 12 months experience

Comment: Exactly. Now i'm almost 11 months. Before I join this current workplace, I worked in another company for 10 months. So, If i talk with HR, asking for change my designation to ASE, will it be a reasonable request ?

Comment: We can't tell you if it's reasonable you should change straight away: we'd need to know exactly what their definitions of the roles are, and more about whether you meet them - we can't judge. But you can certainly ask them if that's the job you applied for, and if they say no find out how you earn the promotion.