# Is it reasonable to complain about the 'junior' label after entering the company with 4 years of experience?

Tags: professionalism, seniority

I've been with my current employer for three months. When they presented me their offer, I explicitly asked about seniority and was assured that my position would be mid-senior level and even that there are no junior-level employees at this branch. The chief officer I was speaking to also established that there is an evaluation at the six-month mark to renegotiate pay etc. For context, I'm a web developer working at an agency. My paperwork makes no mention of seniority or titles

My responsibilities and performance since joining have supported my assumption that I am employed as a mid-level engineer: I have built applications from scratch, worked on projects without supervision, am one of the very few people communicating with clients directly on a daily basis. I've received good feedback and a bonus.

I've only become aware of the 'junior' label after being invited to fill out an internal-use profile, where it is pre-set as my description. I can't see anyone else's profile and cannot establish a comparison.

A relevant factor might be that I am of an age where most people are just entering the workforce. However I was gainfully employed in the industry throughout my studies and advanced my skills clearly and consistently. I haven't held a junior position in two years.

My question is: would it be reasonable and/or appropriate to bring this up with HR or my team lead, or is it better to wait for my six month evaluation? I expected a promotion at that time; I don't see myself staying with the company if that promotion is to the level at which I thought I'd started. I'd really appreciate advice on how to handle this appropriately.

I care about this title because of it alters my position in any salary or advancement negotiation and it was done in a non-transparent way, which changes how I see the communication with my supervisors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ask for higher title when negotiating with current employer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/ask-for-higher-title-when-negotiating-with-current-employer)

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I don't think it is. I'm preparing to voice a concern, and there is the potential that my company actually holds me in much lower regard than I believed. Additionally I might be in the exact opposite situation, although some answers that question got help establish how people view titles in general.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54477/discussion-on-question-by-lostrack-is-it-reasonable-to-complain-about-the-junio).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I explicitly asked about seniority and **was assured that my position would be mid-senior level** and even that there are no junior-level employees at this branch.

I personally don't feel titles are trivial at all. Titles reflect how the company sees you. If the person to talk to is the "HR Manager" ask how he/she would feel about being called "HR Specialist" or tell the HR person to ask if the "VP Finance" would see being called "Junior VP Finance" as something trivial.

I think it's more than reasonable, I think you should absolutely talk to someone about it. I think your 6-month promotion concern as a result is also reasonable.

While your employment contract didn't say anything specific about the title, you were told that it wouldn't be junior. While that's obviously not legally binding, it certainly will tell you about the company if they fail to honor that agreement.

I would take it up with HR and pose it as an apparent mistake, possibly a typo (i.e. giving them the benefit of the doubt) and want to make sure that the correct title is in place.  You may have to talk to the person who made the promise though to get it done but I think it's worthwhile to do.

Comment: Also, in some jurisdictions, like Australia, job titles can affect what award you are entitled to - setting limits on pay and other things (overtime expectations, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your contributions to this thread. I understand some users are wary of people who are obsessed with titles to the exclusion of all else, but I feel that I am at the initial stage of my career where my employer's estimation is of special importance. 


I think I will address this directly with the officer who made me the offer and discussed this with me initially. I will ask about my position in the context of other changes happening soon, and if he maintains that I'm a medium-level employee, I'll have something concrete and timely to point to when speaking to HR.

Comment: @lostrack I'd genuinely be interested to know how it works out. I view titles as labels on a can. Putting a Chicken Noodle label on a can of Vegetable Beef soup doesn't change the contents of the soup but it does help to tell you what's inside. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what industry you are in, however in my experience titles are not trivial and in some cases, am error in someone's title may have serious ramifications for both the company and the employee. It's definitely worth clarifying with management and getting it straightened out. Especially since bonuses and pay increases often depend on pay grade, wheich is reflected in job title.

In my case, I was working with a lot of contract engineers on product approvals for surgical tools, which are regulated by the FDA. Part of the requirements are that these be signed off by an Engineer. I discovered that HR had most of us classified as "Technicians", which, had the error remains uncorrected, would have invalidated all of the approvals we had done. Had the FDA discovered that Technicians were issuing these approvals they would have gone on a rampage.

The other engineers, who were mostly right out of university, didn't seem to care as long as they were getting paid. That is until I pointed out that they may not work there forever and asked them to think about what would happen if they had "Engineer" on their resume as their job title but when a potential employer called to check, they were told, "Yes, so-and-so worked here as a Technician...". That throws their entire resume and integrity into question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! I'm a web developer working in an agency (end of first paragraph). Our titles don't carry importance to the degree you describe - but a misalignment could still cause issues, especially if I didn't know it even existed...

Answer (score -5):

**Titles are trivial**

Your next job isn't going to care what your title was - they're going to care what you had experience doing. Regardless of if your next job is with another company or this one, the concept is the same - you should be more worried about what you are *doing* than what your title is.

If you're leading a team of developers, whether your title is "juniorest developer" or not, you will be able to apply to dev lead roles - as you have experience doing that.

Similarly, you can always give yourself a title as "CEO" and file paper work to start a company - but not even Yahoo! will interview you for an actual CEO role.

You can always ask to change your title in the company, but honestly I don't think it matters. Your performance/raises should be based on the value you add, not the title you live under.
Also, you're perfectly within your right to put your title as whatever you want on your CV - 99.999% of companies will only check that you worked the dates you gave in a background check, not whatever title you had.

Comment: Absolutely untrue. If you put "Lead Engineer"  for a job on your resume, maybe because you beleive that's what it was and when a potential employer calls to verify that employment hears that your title was "Junior Developer"...it won't look good.

Comment: Then don't put the title like that - put it as "Functioned as Lead Engineer" and then in bullet points list what lead engineer work you did (mentoring, architecture, etc).

Comment: Personally (and this is not unusual at all) - I want my career to follow a particular trajectory and I try my best to have my employer support and affirm that I am on track. While what you're saying could be relevant for some future career prospects, it's not really what I'm asking about.

That being said, if I find a company I work for is actively sabotaging my ability to leave / find better opportunities in the future, I'll bust out my creative CV writing skills.

Comment: That distinction will likely be lost on any potential employer and would be viewed as "title inflation". I know that's how I'd look at it when considering a candidate. I'd certainly question it.

Comment: You're looking at it from the perspective of a hiring manager in a startup, but the truth of the matter is, in large companies HR can also be involved in those types of decisions. And lacking the knowledge to judge the candidate/employee any other way, non-technical HR specialists will fall back on tracking the only parts that can be verified. So they may look at titles and buzzwords when weeding out resumes, or when implementing employee policy decisions, or even when doing background checks. For example, see http://www.city-data.com/forum/work-employment/2302168-sample-hireright-report.html

Comment: In some countries, titles are really trivial, so not sure what is up with all these downvotes. The world is very diverse, and so are companies. Where I work, there are software engineers with 20 years of experience sharing the same title with fresh graduates. Northern Europe.